# How to execute an a.out file by using exec function family in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, exec

The aim of this c++ program is about the understanding the cocurrent process mechanism in operating system. And the following code is for the child functions of one process. And the child process have theirs numbers, NO.5 and NO.6.

I'm trying to exectute an a.out file in the NO.6 process. I'm trying to do it this way.

```
void ChildFunction_For_ProcessNO.4(int i){
    switch(i){
        case(5):
            cout << "This is process five, and the ID for this process is " << getpid() << '\n'
                 << "and the ID for the parent process is " << getppid() << '\n';
            CreateThreads_Five();
            cout << "Process five has ended.\n" << '\n';
            break;
        case(6):
            cout << "This is process six, and the ID for this process is " << getpid() << '\n'
                 << "and the ID for the parent process is " << getppid() << '\n';
            execl("./a.out", "a.out", NULL);
            //and I also tried this way
            execl("Home/CLionProjects/Project_1/a.out", "a.out", NULL);
            char buf[100]; 
            cout << "getcwd: " << getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf))) << endl;
            cout << "Process six has ended.\n";
            break;
    }
```

and the getcwd's output goes like this

```
getcwd: /home/chengxuyuan/CLionProjects/Project_1/cmake-build-debug
```

The a.out file has already been put in the folder together with the c++ program.
[the screenshot of the working directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2POZ.png)
and the compile went well, but there is just no output which ought to be `Hello world` from the a.out file. How can I solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: We'll need a minimal working code sample - i.e. something that we can copy and compile ourselves - to be able to help you.

Comment: Is `a.out` in the current working directory of the parent program?  What happens if you pass the full absolute path of `a.out` as the first arg to `execl`?

Comment: Add a line `perror("execl");` after the `execl()` call to show the error in case `execl` returns.

Comment: @Bodo the output is ```No such file or directory```

Comment: @G.M. I have put the ```a.out``` file in the current working directory. And there is still no output after giving the full path of ```a.out```.

Comment: @GeckoGeorge there you have it. Thank you.

Comment: @Reus Please [edit] your question and add all information there instead of answering in a comment. Maybe the current working directory is not what you think it is. Please print the result of `getcwd`, e.g. char buf[100]; std::cout << "getcwd: " << getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf))) << std::endl;` How exactly do you start your program? In your screenshot the file `a.out` is where your sourcecode `main.cpp` is located. Your executable program probably is somewhere in `cmake-build-debug`. Please also show the code that tries to execute `a.out` with a full path.

Comment: @Bodo I added more info. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Bodo Deeply appreciate for your help. The code you provide has helped a lot. I have been brothered by this problem for a couple of days. With your code now I know it is something wrong with the path. I am just a beginner of Linux. I still got a lot to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `getcwd` output shows that you have to put your file `a.out` into

```
/home/chengxuyuan/CLionProjects/Project_1/cmake-build-debug
```

Your attempt

```
execl("Home/CLionProjects/Project_1/a.out", "a.out", NULL);
```

is wrong this is not the full path. You would have to use

```
execl("/home/chengxuyuan/CLionProjects/Project_1/a.out", "a.out", NULL);
```

**BTW:** You should specify the same value as argument 0 as you use for the program to be run, i.e.

```
execl("/home/chengxuyuan/CLionProjects/Project_1/a.out", "/home/chengxuyuan/CLionProjects/Project_1/a.out", NULL);
```

or

```
execl("./a.out", "./a.out", NULL);
```

This is what the shell would do and what most programs expect.

Comment: Thank you again, truly!

Comment: If this is what you need you can accept the answer. (Maybe you have to wait for some time to be able to accept it.)